# How to set define precedence of one match above another in regular expression

Tags: regex, key-value

I have logfiles from which i need to extract the key and value pairs for each logged line using the following format.

```
[2018-11-19T13:04:33.031+01:00]  Bedrijfsdocument="BD-023005 Document" Richting="Uitgaand" Status="verzonden"; Zaaknummer="2323343333"; MessageID="ef5c6e9e-849e-4d80-af86-92fc127e7178"; ConversationID="5571c03e-62a8-4fce-81ff-9fe31b7b276c"; RefToMessageId="34333139343034303934303135343731"; MMDBestand="2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_0_MMD.mmd"; Bericht="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:DocumentBericht BDVersie="2.1" BDNaam="TA-022305" xmlns:ns2="com.my.test/berichten/document/2" xmlns="com.my.test/header/1"><Header><ID>58b5708f-4115-462c-93f3-5fb5134c9e25</ID><VerzendendePartijen><VerzendendePartij><Volgnummer>1</Volgnummer><RegistratieveRelatiePartij><Identificatie>00000004000000034000_OTA</Identificatie><SoortRegistratie>15</SoortRegistratie></RegistratieveRelatiePartij></VerzendendePartij></VerzendendePartijen><OntvangendePartijen><OntvangendePartij><Volgnummer>1</Volgnummer><RegistratieveRelatiePartij><Identificatie>00000004000000076000_OTA</Identificatie><SoortRegistratie>15</SoortRegistratie></RegistratieveRelatiePartij></OntvangendePartij></OntvangendePartijen><Datum>2018-11-19</Datum><Tijd>13:04:32.952+01:00</Tijd><SchemaVersieID>1.1</SchemaVersieID></Header><ns2:Zaak><ns2:Identificatie>2100008418</ns2:Identificatie></ns2:Zaak><ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveaus><ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveau><ns2:Classificatie><ns2:DocumentSoort>098</ns2:DocumentSoort></ns2:Classificatie><ns2:Identificatiekenmerk>DOC006256</ns2:Identificatiekenmerk><ns2:Foldernaam>02 - Correspondentie</ns2:Foldernaam><ns2:Revisie>1</ns2:Revisie><ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata>0</ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata><ns2:Naam>02 - Toezenden stukken rm</ns2:Naam><ns2:Bijlage><ns2:MimeContent><ns2:MimeContentType>application/pdf</ns2:MimeContentType><ns2:MimeContentId>2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_2.pdf@my.com</ns2:MimeContentId></ns2:MimeContent></ns2:Bijlage></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveau></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveaus></ns2:DocumentBericht>"; Omvang="3512"
```

This is currently parsed using the following regular expression to extract the name and value pairs.

```
(?:^\[.*\])?(?:[\s]+)(?<key>[^=]+)(?:={1}"{1})(?<value>[^"]+)(?:["]{1})
```

It works fine, except for the key 'Bericht' which contains xml and also non-escaped quote's. The content of this key is a fact for me, so should handle this in my code to parse the logline. So i am looking for a way to define the end of a parameter value which is " or >" where >" should take precedence over ".

I use the following test code

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern keyValuePairsPattern = Pattern.compile("(?:^\\[.*\\])?(?:[\\s]+)(?<key>[^=]+)(?:={1}\"{1})(?<value>[^\"]+)(?:[\"]{1})");
    String logentry = "[2018-11-19T13:04:33.031+01:00]  Bedrijfsdocument=\"BD-023005 Document\" Richting=\"Uitgaand\" Status=\"verzonden\"; Zaaknummer=\"2323343333\"; MessageID=\"ef5c6e9e-849e-4d80-af86-92fc127e7178\"; ConversationID=\"5571c03e-62a8-4fce-81ff-9fe31b7b276c\"; RefToMessageId=\"34333139343034303934303135343731\"; MMDBestand=\"2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_0_MMD.mmd\"; Bericht=\"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><ns2:DocumentBericht BDVersie=\"2.1\" BDNaam=\"TA-022305\" xmlns:ns2=\"com.my.test/berichten/document/2\" xmlns=\"com.my.test/header/1\"><Header><ID>58b5708f-4115-462c-93f3-5fb5134c9e25</ID><VerzendendePartijen><VerzendendePartij><Volgnummer>1</Volgnummer><RegistratieveRelatiePartij><Identificatie>00000004000000034000_OTA</Identificatie><SoortRegistratie>15</SoortRegistratie></RegistratieveRelatiePartij></VerzendendePartij></VerzendendePartijen><OntvangendePartijen><OntvangendePartij><Volgnummer>1</Volgnummer><RegistratieveRelatiePartij><Identificatie>00000004000000076000_OTA</Identificatie><SoortRegistratie>15</SoortRegistratie></RegistratieveRelatiePartij></OntvangendePartij></OntvangendePartijen><Datum>2018-11-19</Datum><Tijd>13:04:32.952+01:00</Tijd><SchemaVersieID>1.1</SchemaVersieID></Header><ns2:Zaak><ns2:Identificatie>2100008418</ns2:Identificatie></ns2:Zaak><ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveaus><ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveau><ns2:Classificatie><ns2:DocumentSoort>098</ns2:DocumentSoort></ns2:Classificatie><ns2:Identificatiekenmerk>DOC006256</ns2:Identificatiekenmerk><ns2:Foldernaam>02 - Correspondentie</ns2:Foldernaam><ns2:Revisie>1</ns2:Revisie><ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata>0</ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata><ns2:Naam>02 - Toezenden stukken rm</ns2:Naam><ns2:Bijlage><ns2:MimeContent><ns2:MimeContentType>application/pdf</ns2:MimeContentType><ns2:MimeContentId>2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_2.pdf@my.com</ns2:MimeContentId></ns2:MimeContent></ns2:Bijlage></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveau></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveaus></ns2:DocumentBericht>\"; Omvang=\"3512\"";

    // Extract Key value pairs
    Matcher paramMatcher = keyValuePairsPattern.matcher(logentry);
    while (paramMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(paramMatcher.group("key") + "<=>" + paramMatcher.group("value"));
    }
}
```

}

Which gives the result

```
Bedrijfsdocument<=>BD-023005 Document
Richting<=>Uitgaand
Status<=>verzonden
Zaaknummer<=>2323343333
MessageID<=>ef5c6e9e-849e-4d80-af86-92fc127e7178
ConversationID<=>5571c03e-62a8-4fce-81ff-9fe31b7b276c
RefToMessageId<=>34333139343034303934303135343731
MMDBestand<=>2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_0_MMD.mmd
Bericht<=><?xml version=
encoding<=>UTF-8
standalone<=>yes
BDVersie<=>2.1
BDNaam<=>TA-022305
xmlns:ns2<=>com.my.test/berichten/document/2
xmlns<=>com.my.test/header/1
- Correspondentie</ns2:Foldernaam><ns2:Revisie>1</ns2:Revisie><ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata>0</ns2:IndicatieGewijzigdeMetadata><ns2:Naam>02 - Toezenden stukken rm</ns2:Naam><ns2:Bijlage><ns2:MimeContent><ns2:MimeContentType>application/pdf</ns2:MimeContentType><ns2:MimeContentId>2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_2.pdf@my.com</ns2:MimeContentId></ns2:MimeContent></ns2:Bijlage></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveau></ns2:DocumentAggregatieniveaus></ns2:DocumentBericht>"; Omvang<=>3512
```

The desired result should would be

```
Bedrijfsdocument<=>BD-023005 Document
Richting<=>Uitgaand
Status<=>verzonden
Zaaknummer<=>2323343333
MessageID<=>ef5c6e9e-849e-4d80-af86-92fc127e7178
ConversationID<=>5571c03e-62a8-4fce-81ff-9fe31b7b276c
RefToMessageId<=>34333139343034303934303135343731
MMDBestand<=>2018-11-19_9bf1caf8-ca3d-43ae-b046-fa44142faa36_0_MMD.mmd
Bericht<=><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" .....       
Omvang<=>3512
```

I tried to add another non-capture group with an optional "<" before the closing quote of the parameter value, but this does not resolve the issue.

```
(?:^\[.*\])?(?:[\s]+)(?<key>[^=]+)(?:={1}"{1})(?<value>[^"]+)(?:>?)(?:["]{1})
```

What i probably need is an expression that defines the end of a value by a " or a <" where <" takes precedence over ".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `{1}` in any of your regexes, it does nothing as it is the default behavior: each pattern is matched once if not quantified in any other way. See [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: Thanks for making the regex better, but it does not answer my question though.

Comment: Note I suggested leaving out `(?:^\[.*\])?` from the pattern because the timestamp is not likely to contain `=` and will not make any difference. If you ever need to put it back, use `(?:^\[[^\]\[]*])?` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\s(?<key>[^=\s]+)="(?<value>(?:<[^<>]*>|[^"])*)"
```

In Java:

```
String pat = "\\s(?<key>[^=\\s]+)=\"(?<value>(?:<[^<>]*>|[^\"])*)\"";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7aez60/2). The first `\s` can even be omitted, but it makes it more efficient.

**Details**

- `\s` - whitespace
- `(?<key>[^=\s]+)` - Group "key": 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `="` - a literal text
- `(?<value>(?:<[^<>]*>|[^"])*)` - Group "value": any substring between `<` and `>` with no `<`/`>` (`<[^<>]*>`) inside or (`|`) any char other than a double quotation mark (`[^"]`)
- `"` - a double quote

Comment: Took me some time to understand the `<[^<>]*>` part, but works like a charm. 
Learned something again, thanks!